# Scripts all Sprocs at once with DROP and CREATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

**Goal:** To generate scripts for creating sprocs that are already in the DB. Must be one script per file.

I know I can simply right click the database and 'Tasks>Generate Scripts', but that doesn't script the sproc in the template I want.

I need the sproc to be scripted in the same template you get when you right click the sproc from the object explorer and 'Script Stored Procedure As>DROP and CREATE'.

It's true you get a similar version of this through 'Tasks>Generate Scripts' but the main difference is the 'Tasks>Generate Scripts' method creates the script via the `dbo.sp_executesql` command because you cannot nest a `CREATE PROCEDURE` inside of an `IF` block

Tasks>Generate produces this:

```
USE someDB
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'somesproc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE someSproc
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'someSproc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE 
AS
BEGIN

END
' 
END
GO
```

But I require this (as found from right clicking the sproc):

```
USE someDB
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'someSproc') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE someSproc
GO

USE someDB
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE someSproc

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

END

GO
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be solved with CREATE OR REPLACE - have you voted / commented? :-) http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/127219/create-or-replace

Comment: Some questions about your desired output. Do you need `USE someDB` between each statement? I assume it's ok to ignore permissions and dependency order, that kind of thing?

Comment: Only need the single `USE someDB`. And yes, those two can be ignored.

Comment: Just voted! That would be the perfect feature for this!

Comment: Okay, and finally, does the output need to be in separate files (e.g. for source control) or can it result in one humungous script that you're just going to run elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In order to create the scripts from SSMS...**

**Step 1 - create the scripting stored procedure:**

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM sys.objects 
  WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_ScriptProcedure]') 
  AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ScriptProcedure]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ScriptProcedure] (
  @ObjectID INT,
  @Name NVARCHAR(128),
  @SchemaID INT
) 
AS 

DECLARE 
  @code VARCHAR(MAX),
  @newLine CHAR(2)

SET @newLine = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

SET @code = 
    'USE [' + DB_NAME() + ']' + @newLine + 'GO' + @newLine + @newLine
    + 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = '
    + 'OBJECT_ID(N''[' + SCHEMA_NAME(@schemaID) + '].[' + @Name + ']'') ' 
    + 'AND type IN (N''P'', N''PC''))' + @newLine 
    + 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(@schemaID) + '].[' + @name + ']' 
    + @newLine + @newLine + 'SET ANSI_NULLS ON' + @newLine + 'GO' 
    + @newLine + @newLine + 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON' + @newLine + 'GO'
    + @newLine + @newLine
    + OBJECT_DEFINITION(@ObjectID) + @newLine + 'GO' 
    + @newLine + @newLine + 'SET ANSI_NULLS OFF' + @newLine + 'GO' 
    + @newLine + @newLine + 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF' + @newLine + 'GO'

WHILE @code <> ''
BEGIN
  PRINT LEFT(@code,8000)
  SET @code = SUBSTRING(@code, 8001, LEN(@code))
END
GO
```

**Step 2 - enable xp_cmdshell**

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

**Step 3 - run the script below (be sure to set server name and folder destination)**

```
DECLARE 
  @name sysname,
  @objID int,
  @schemaID int,
  @cmd varchar(1000),
  @folder varchar(128),
  @server varchar(128)

SET @server = 'MSSQL'  
SET @folder = 'C:\Scripts'

DECLARE procs CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name, object_id, schema_id 
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY [name]
OPEN procs

FETCH NEXT FROM procs
INTO @name, @objID, @schemaID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S .\' + @server + ' -d ' + DB_NAME() 
           + ' -Q "EXEC usp_ScriptProcedure ' 
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @objID) + ', N'''
           + @name + ''', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @schemaID) 
           + '" > ' + @folder + '\' + @name + '.sql'

  EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd

  FETCH NEXT FROM procs
  INTO @name, @objID, @schemaID

END

CLOSE procs
DEALLOCATE procs
```

**References:**

- [How to script all stored procedures in a database](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-script-all-stored-procedures-in-a)
- [sys.procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188737.aspx)
- [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this (in PowerShell, not through Management Studio):

```
$server      = "GREENLANTERN\SQL2008R2"   # server
$database    = "AdventureWorks"           # database
$folder      = "C:\target\"               # output folder
$conn_string = "Data Source=$server;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated Security=SSPI"

$conn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($conn_string);
$conn.open();

$query = "SELECT
      n = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])) 
          + '.' + QUOTENAME(name),
      d = OBJECT_DEFINITION([object_id]),
      f = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) 
          + '_' + name
    FROM " + $database + ".sys.procedures;";

$command = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand $query, $conn

$reader = $command.ExecuteReader();

while ($reader.Read())
{
    $procname = $reader.GetValue(0);
    $crscript = $reader.GetValue(1);
    $filename = $reader.GetValue(2);

    $output = "    USE [$database];
    GO

    IF EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT 1 
            FROM sys.procedures 
            WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID($procname)
    )
    BEGIN
        DROP PROCEDURE $procname;
    END
    GO

    $crscript
    GO";

    $file = "$folder$filename.sql";
    $output | out-file $file; #might need -encoding ASCII;     
}
```

I've left out error-handling, proper GC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

i modified the stored procedure to generate scripts for tables like this:

```
DECLARE tabls CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name, object_id, schema_id  
FROM sys.Tables
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0  
ORDER BY [name] 
OPEN tabls 

FETCH NEXT FROM tabls 
INTO @name, @objID, @schemaID 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 

  SET @cmd = 'sqlcmd -S .\' + @server + ' -d ' + DB_NAME()  
           + ' -Q "EXEC usp_ScriptProcedure '  
           + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @objID) + ', N''' 
           + @name + ''', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @schemaID)  
           + '" > ' + @folder_Tbl + '\' + @name + '.sql' 

  EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd 

  FETCH NEXT FROM tabls 
  INTO @name, @objID, @schemaID 

END 

CLOSE tabls 
DEALLOCATE tabls
```